# iPad UISplitViewController - pushing new detail view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` in my iPad app and when the user selects a button on the master `UIViewController`, I'd like to push a new `UIViewController` on the detail side, but keep the same master `UIViewController`.

However, what happens is the new detail `UIViewController` comes up, but the master `UIViewController` is replaced with a blank white screen. I'm using:

```
[[DataCenter currentDetailViewController] presentViewController:svc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

How can I keep the master `UIViewController` on the screen when I push a new detail `UIViewController`?

[image]

Comment: And why would you want to do that? The whole reason if detail->master is that master is based on detailed (like settings). If you want to break that relation, you shouldn't use master-detail view controllers, instead either use container views or child viewcontrollers.

Comment: Because this is how my app is set up. Do I really need to go into the details of the app to explain why this is useful for my particular app? I doubt it. So your answer is: this is not possible using UISplitViewController?

Comment: After taking a look at UISplitViewController delegate, I can't find any method that could be used to control the master page. If master and detail aren't related (ex: they have a tree-like structure), then you should use two individual view controller.

Comment: Could this be what you are trying to accomplish: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html